# Achieving literal text search combined with subword matching in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, n-gram

I have populated an Elasticsearch database using the following settings:

```json
mapping = {
    "properties": {
        "location": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer"
        },
        "description": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer"
        },
        "commentaar": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer"
        },
    }
}


    settings = {
        "settings": {
            "analysis": {
                "filter": {
                    "ngram_filter": {
                        "type": "ngram",
                        "min_gram": 1,
                        "max_gram": 20
                    }
                },
                "analyzer": {
                    "ngram_analyzer": {
                        "type": "custom",
                        "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                        "filter": [
                            "lowercase",
                            "ngram_filter"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "mappings": {"custom_tool": mapping}
    }
```

I used the ngram analyser because I wanted the be able to have subword matching. So a search for "ackoverfl" would return the entries containing "stackoverflow".

My search queries are made as follows:

```json
    q = {
        "simple_query_string": {
            "query": needle,
            "default_operator": "and",
            "analyzer": "whitespace"
        }
    }
```

Where needle is the text from my search bar.
Sometimes I would also like to do literal phrase searching. For example:
If my search term is:

> "the ap hangs in the tree"

(Notice that I use quotation marks here with the intention the search for a literal piece of text).

Then in my results I get a document containing:

> the apple hangs in the tree

This results is unwanted.

How could I implement having a subword matching search capability while also having the option to search for literal phrases (by using for example quotation marks) ?